# Исправить (подсказать) ошибку. файл

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Программа писалась на программе pascal.net

**Задача**
 Даны строки S1, S2 и файл-архив целых чисел, содержащий данные
из нескольких файлов в формате, описанном в задании File55. Создать
новые файлы целых чисел с именами S1 и S2 и записать в первый из них
начальные элементы всех файлов, содержащихся в архиве, а во второй —
конечные элементы этих файлов (в том же порядке).

**Ошибка в компиляции**
57.pas(23) : Ошибка времени выполнения: Входная строка имела неверный формат.

```
  While not eof(F_in) do
 begin
 Read (F_in,len);
for i2:=1 to len do
 begin
  Read (F_in,temp);
  if i2=1 then Write(F_out_begin,temp);
  if i2=len then Write(F_out_end,temp);
 end;
end;
```

**Полный лист программы если потребуется**

```
program File57;
var
S: String;
F_in:text;
F_out_begin,F_out_end:File of Integer;
i2,len,temp: integer;

begin

Write('Archive File: ');
Readln(S);
Assign(F_in,S);
 Reset(F_in);

 Assign(F_out_begin,'s1.data');
 ReWrite(F_out_begin);

 Assign(F_out_end,'s2.data');
 ReWrite(F_out_end);

  While not eof(F_in) do
  begin
  Read (F_in,len);
  for i2:=1 to len do
   begin
   Read (F_in,temp);
    if i2=1 then Write(F_out_begin,temp);
   if i2=len then Write(F_out_end,temp);
   end;
   end;
  reset(F_out_begin);
  writeln('Исходный файл:');
   while not eof(F_out_begin) do
  begin
  read(F_out_begin,temp);
 write(' ',temp);
 end;
 reset(F_out_end);
 writeln('Исходный файл:');
 while not eof(F_out_end) do
begin
read(F_out_end,temp);
write(' ',temp);
end;
Close(F_in);
 Close(F_out_begin);
 Close(F_out_end);
 end.
```

Comment: `Read (F_in,len);` - что в файле входных данных?

Comment: @Igor 5 файлов текстовых в архиве (как понял по условию задачи) считаются в F_in. А дальше ошибка происходит

Comment: `i2,len,**tem**: integer;` и `Read (F_in,**temp**);` - это вы скопировали неправильно или в самой программе так же?

Comment: @Alekcvp Спасибо исправил. Это когда сюда копировал нечаянно удалил одну букву и не заметил.